# ORA-01427 Single-Row Subquery Returns More than One Row - how to resolve?

Tags: oracle, bi-publisher, ora-01427

I've had this query running for over 2 years and just recently this began throwing the ORA-01427 single row sub-query returns multiple rows error. What's the best way to debug this when there are multiple sub-queries? Should I be adding a MAX statement to each subquery? I've tried switching some of the = operators to IN but that's not working and I'm not confident it would give me the correct results either.

Appreciate any insight or assistance this community can provide. I'm ripping my hair out working through this one!

```
SELECT
        NVL(
                (SELECT 
                'Y'
                FROM 
                PER_ASSIGNMENT_SUPERVISORS_F 
                WHERE
                 MANAGER_ID = PAPF.PERSON_ID
                AND  MANAGER_TYPE ='LINE_MANAGER'
                AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
                AND ROWNUM = 1),'N') MANAGER_FLAG,
PAAM.ASSIGNMENT_STATUS_TYPE,
PAAM.EMPLOYMENT_CATEGORY,
TO_CHAR(PPOS.DATE_START,'YYYY-MM-DD') AS HIRE_DATE,
PER_EXTRACT_UTILITY.GET_STANDARD_WORKING_HOURS(PAAM.ASSIGNMENT_ID,TRUNC(SYSDATE)) AS STANDARD_WORKING_HOURS,
TO_CHAR(PAAM.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') AS EFFECTIVE_START_DATE,

                (
                        SELECT 
                        PJFVL.JOB_CODE
                        FROM 
                        PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_M PAAM1,
                        PER_JOBS_F_VL PJFVL
                        WHERE 
                        PAAM1.PERSON_ID = PASF.MANAGER_ID
                        AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PAAM1.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND PAAM1.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
                        AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PJFVL.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND PJFVL.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
                        and PAAM1.ASSIGNMENT_STATUS_TYPE='ACTIVE'
                        AND PAAM1.ASSIGNMENT_TYPE = 'E'
                        AND PAAM1.effective_latest_change = 'Y' 
                        AND PJFVL.JOB_ID = PAAM1.JOB_ID

)as Manager_job_code,


                (
                        SELECT 
                                     HOIF.ORG_INFORMATION1 
                        FROM 

                        PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_M PAAM2,
                        HR_ORGANIZATION_INFORMATION_F HOIF

                        WHERE 

                        PAAM2.PERSON_ID = PASF.MANAGER_ID
                        AND HOIF.ORG_INFORMATION_CONTEXT = 'DEPT_DET'
                        and PAAM2.ASSIGNMENT_STATUS_TYPE='ACTIVE'
                        AND PAAM2.ASSIGNMENT_TYPE = 'E'
                        AND PAAM2.effective_latest_change = 'Y' 
                        AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PAAM2.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND PAAM2.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
                        AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN HOIF.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND HOIF.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
                        AND  HOIF.ORGANIZATION_ID = PAAM2.ORGANIZATION_ID

) as Manager_dep_code,


(SELECT 
            COUNT(PPOS.PERIOD_OF_SERVICE_ID)
            FROM

            PER_PERIODS_OF_SERVICE PPOS
            WHERE 
            1 = 1
            AND PAAM.PERSON_ID = PPOS.PERSON_ID
) AS INACTIVE_WORKRELATIONSHIP,

PAPF.PERSON_NUMBER as SAMACCOUNTNAME,

(SELECT CSB.NAME FROM 
        CMP_SALARY CS,
        CMP_SALARY_BASES CSB
        WHERE 
        CS.ASSIGNMENT_ID = PAAM.ASSIGNMENT_ID
        AND CS.SALARY_BASIS_ID = CSB.SALARY_BASIS_ID
        and TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN CS.DATE_FROM AND CS.DATE_TO
) AS hourly_salary_Paid,

TO_CHAR(PP.DATE_OF_BIRTH,'YYYY-MM-DD') AS DOB,
PPNFV.LAST_NAME,
PPNFV.FIRST_NAME,
HLA.LOCATION_NAME as Location,
HLA.ADDRESS_LINE_1 AS LOC_ADDRESS_1,
HLA.ADDRESS_LINE_2 AS LOC_ADDRESS_2,
HLA.TOWN_OR_CITY AS City,
HLA.POSTAL_CODE AS ZIP_CODE,
HLA.REGION_2 AS STATE,
PPNFV.KNOWN_AS AS PREFERRED_NAME,
TRIM((PPNFV.KNOWN_AS||' '||PPNFV.LAST_NAME)) AS PREFERRED_NAME_LAST_NAME,
(SELECT 
        PPNFV.DISPLAY_NAME 
        FROM  per_person_names_f_v PPNFV
        WHERE  1 = 1
        AND PPNFV.PERSON_ID = PASF.MANAGER_ID
        AND PPNFV.NAME_TYPE='GLOBAL'
        AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PPNFV.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND PPNFV.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
) AS  MANAGER_NAME,
(SELECT 
        PAPF.PERSON_NUMBER
        FROM PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F PAPF
        WHERE PAPF.PERSON_ID = PASF.MANAGER_ID
        AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PAPF.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND PAPF.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
) AS  MANAGER_NUMBER,
HAOUFVL.NAME  AS DEPARTMENT,
PAAM.ASSIGNMENT_NAME AS JOB_TILE,
PLE.NAME as Company,
PJLG.INFORMATION1 AS FLSA,
SUBSTR(PNI.NATIONAL_IDENTIFIER_NUMBER,-4) AS SSN_NUMBER,
PAAM.ASS_ATTRIBUTE1 as Officer_TITLE,
(
         select
          bu.name
         from  
         hr_all_organization_units_f_vl bu
         where 1 = 1
         and paam.business_unit_id = bu.organization_id
         and trunc(sysdate) between bu.effective_start_date and bu.effective_end_date

) as BUS_UNIT,
TO_CHAR (PPOS.ORIGINAL_DATE_OF_HIRE,'YYYY-MM-DD') AS ORIGINAL_DATE_OF_HIRE1,

(
            CASE  WHEN PPLF.SEX = 'F' THEN 
            'TRUE'
            ELSE
            'FALSE'
            END 
) AS GENDER,

(
            CASE  WHEN PJFFVL.JOB_FAMILY_NAME  = 'Executive' THEN 
            'ELT'
            ELSE
            ' '
            END 
) AS ELT_DESIGNATION,

HOIF.ORG_INFORMATION1 as DEPATMENT_CODE,
PJFV.JOB_CODE  AS JOB_CODE,
PAF.ADDRESS_LINE_1 AS HOME_ADDRESS_LINE_1,
PAF.ADDRESS_LINE_2 AS HOME_ADDRESS_LINE_2,
PAF.TOWN_OR_CITY AS HOW_ADDRESS_CITY,
PAF.REGION_2 AS HOME_ADDRESS_STATE,
PAF.POSTAL_CODE AS HOME_ADRESS_ZIP_CODE,
PGFTL.NAME as Grade_level,
(SELECT 
        distinct (per_extract_utility.get_decoded_lookup('JOB_FUNCTION_CODE',PJF.JOB_FUNCTION_CODE))
        FROM           
        PER_JOB_SECURED_LIST_V job WHERE TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN effective_start_date AND effective_end_date
) as JOB_FUNCTION,
pp.attribute1 as PER_NETWORKID,
(SELECT 
        PPNFV.attribute1 
        FROM  PER_PERSONS PPNFV
        WHERE 1 = 1
        AND PPNFV.PERSON_ID = PASF.MANAGER_ID
) AS  MANAGER_NETWORKID,
HOIF.ORG_INFORMATION2 AS REGION,
to_char(paam.ass_attribute_date1,'MM/DD/YYYY') as OfficerPromoDate
FROM 
PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_M PAAM,
PER_ASSIGNMENT_SUPERVISORS_F PASF,
PER_PERIODS_OF_SERVICE PPOS,
PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F PAPF,
PER_PERSONS PP,
per_person_names_f_v PPNFV,

HR_LOCATIONS_ALL HLA,
HR_ALL_ORGANIZATION_UNITS_F_VL HAOUFVL,
PER_JOB_LEG_F PJLG,
PER_NATIONAL_IDENTIFIERS PNI,
PER_PEOPLE_LEGISLATIVE_F   PPLF,
PER_JOB_FAMILY_F_VL   PJFFVL,
PER_JOBS_F_V PJFV,
HR_ORGANIZATION_INFORMATION_F HOIF,

PER_ADDRESSES_F PAF,
PER_PERSON_ADDR_USAGES_F PPAUF,   
PER_GRADES_F_TL PGFTL,
PER_JOBS_F PJF,
PER_LEGAL_EMPLOYERS PLE,
HR_ALL_ORGANIZATION_UNITS_F HAOUF
WHERE 
PAAM.ASSIGNMENT_STATUS_TYPE='ACTIVE'
AND PAAM.ASSIGNMENT_TYPE = 'E'
AND PAAM.effective_latest_change = 'Y' 
AND PAAM.ASSIGNMENT_ID = PASF.ASSIGNMENT_ID(+)
AND PASF.MANAGER_TYPE (+) = 'LINE_MANAGER'
AND PNI.PERSON_ID(+) = PAAM.PERSON_ID
AND PAAM.PERSON_ID  = PPLF.PERSON_ID(+)
and PJFV.JOB_FAMILY_ID= PJFFVL.JOB_FAMILY_ID(+)
AND PJFV.JOB_ID(+) = PAAM.JOB_ID
AND HOIF.ORGANIZATION_ID(+)= PAAM.ORGANIZATION_ID
AND HOIF.ORG_INFORMATION_CONTEXT(+) = 'DEPT_DETAILS'
AND PPAUF.PERSON_ID(+)= PAPF.PERSON_ID
AND PPAUF.ADDRESS_TYPE (+) = 'HOME'
AND PPAUF.ADDRESS_ID= PAF.ADDRESS_ID(+)
AND PGFTL.GRADE_ID(+)= PAAM.GRADE_ID
AND PJF.JOB_ID(+)= PAAM.JOB_ID
AND PJLG.INFORMATION_CATEGORY='HRX_US_JOBS'
and HAOUF.ORGANIZATION_ID(+)=PLE.ORGANIZATION_ID
and PAAM.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID=PLE.ORGANIZATION_ID
AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PAAM.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE(+) AND PAAM.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE (+)
AND PAAM.PERIOD_OF_SERVICE_ID = PPOS.PERIOD_OF_SERVICE_ID
AND PAPF.PERSON_ID = PAAM.PERSON_ID
AND PP.PERSON_ID = PAAM.PERSON_ID
AND PPNFV.PERSON_ID = PAAM.PERSON_ID
AND HLA.LOCATION_ID(+) = PAAM.LOCATION_ID
AND PJLG.JOB_ID(+) = PAAM.JOB_ID
AND  HAOUFVL.ORGANIZATION_ID(+) = PAAM.ORGANIZATION_ID
AND PPNFV.NAME_TYPE = 'GLOBAL'
AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PPNFV.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND PPNFV.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PAPF.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND PAPF.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE 
AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN HAOUFVL.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE(+) AND HAOUFVL.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE(+)
AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PPLF.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE(+) AND PPLF.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE(+)
AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PJFFVL.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE(+) AND PJFFVL.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE(+)
AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PJFV.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE(+) AND PJFV.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE(+)
AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN HOIF.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE(+) AND HOIF.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE(+)
AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PAF.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE(+) AND PAF.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE(+)
AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PPAUF.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE(+) AND PPAUF.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE(+)
AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PGFTL.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE(+) AND PGFTL.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE(+)
AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PJF.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE(+) AND PJF.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE(+)
AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PLE.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND PLE.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN HAOUF.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE(+) AND HAOUF.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE(+)
AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN HLA.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE(+) AND HLA.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE(+)
AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PJLG.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE(+) AND PJLG.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE(+)
AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PASF.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE(+) AND PASF.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE(+)

ORDER BY PAPF.PERSON_NUMBER
```

Comment: My guess is that your underlying data has recently changed, causing one of the subqueries to return more than one record.

Comment: Thanks Tim, that's what I'm guessing. I'm unsure of how to pinpoint what data or which subquery it is though. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to run the queries without sub queries and then put data in sub queries individually to see if they returns single or multiple records.

Comment: That’s a lot of sub queries. I’d try not to do those. Much easier to diagnose the problem if you use joins.

Answer (score 1):

Run the query in a SQL client that will generate a more detailed error message.  For example, the below code is run in SQL*Plus, which correctly indicates that the problem is with the subquery on line 3.

```
SQL> select
  2     (select 1 from dual) this_will_work,
  3     (select 1 from dba_objects) this_will_fail,
  4     (select 1 from dual) this_will_work
  5  from dual;
   (select 1 from dba_objects) this_will_fail,
    *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```